# Wordpress taxonomy template exclude terms

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom Taxonomy. The lists of terms in the taxonomy will be dynamically created.

I have a custom template for Taxonomy as taxonomy-{custom-template}.php, but I do not want to use the same template for the terms page.

I will not be able to create template for terms upfront as taxonomy-{custom-template}-{term}.php as the terms are created dynamically.

Is there any option to exclude or have a generic template for the terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use is_tax() in your taxonomy-{custom-template}.php to determine whether you are displaying the archive page or the terms page, and them include the relevant code in template parts.

1. Create 2 new template parts in your template parts folder - lets say its called partials

   - One is for your taxonomy archive page e.g.  tax_archive_content.php.
     Copy the archive-specific code from taxonomy-{custom-template}.php
     into it.
   - The other is for your terms page - e.g. tax_terms_content.php. Put your new code for handling the terms in here.
2. Add the following to your taxonomy-{custom-template}.php

(This will replace the archive-specific code that you moved to tax_archive_content.php)

```
if (is_tax())
    get_template_part('partial/tax_archive_content'); 
else
    get_template_part('partial/tax_terms_content');
```

References for `is_tax`:

- Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax
- Developer.wordpress.com:
  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/